# How to search for a specific IPv6 address in a bunch of files?

Tags: grep

Let me first state up front my Linux skills are not top tier. With that being said I tried searching for a specific IPv6 address using grep. My attempt looked like this:

```
# grep -o "2607:f388:2:2001::1002" *.conf
```

I got no results. I am thinking that grep is not liking `:`.

Can someone provide some options?

Comment: It should be ok. Are *.conf in the same-level directory in which you run `grep`?

Comment: Maybe the address is not listed like that. Are you sure it is in one of the files? Try to find it with something like '2607:.*1002". Also, hexadecimal can be upper and lower case, you might want to do that search with `-i`.

Comment: There's nothing special about `:` in a regexp, whatever your problem is, that's not it, and there's nothing else obviously wrong with your command line. You'd have to post sample input and expected output for us to be able to help you.

Comment: The "-i" flag helped. The IPv6 address was using uppercase in the files I was trying to search

Answer (score 0):

As [Eduardo Trápani](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/354526/eduardo-tr%c3%a1pani) noticed in the comments, IPv6 addresses could be upper- or lower-case, so make your grep command ignore case when search by using the `-i` flag:

```
grep -i -o "2607:f388:2:2001::1002" *.conf
```